# Viewpager with webview and listview making scrolling very slow

Tags: android, listview, webview

Here I have a ViewPager with fragments having a ListView each, and some of the cells of the ListView, have WebViews that load MathML expression. To load MathML expressions, I am Using MathJAX library.

Now I understand that having WebViews as ListView items means eating up of more memory and every cell having a browser instance, hence swiping on ViewPager becomes very slow.

I have tried using custom WebViewClients class and also used `hardwareaccelarated = true`, but still no improvement in the performance.

Is there any way I can optimize the performance of the ViewPager?

Comment: try to find an option to use some other native component instead of WebView.

Comment: @AmrutBidri is there any way that we can load mathml using a TextView

Comment: i dont know much about mathml. just tell what data/formatted data is received from mathml lib

Comment: Mostly the data recieved is in Html/CSS format

Comment: if it does not use any javascript to format data as i saw on http://www.mathjax.org/, then u can use textviews. if scripts are required then switch to RecyclerView instead of ListView for app efficiency

Comment: it does uses javascript